# Magento 2 : Override addtocart.phtml for all kinds of products

Tags: magento2, overrides, products

How can I override addtocart.phtml for all types of products, this code works fine only for simple and configurable products, but I want to override all kinds of products.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Eltrino_HideAddCart::css/disableaddtocart.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string"> Module_Cart::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string"> Module_Cart::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to cart button in product page coming from Catalog module with `product/view/addtocart.phtml` template file.
If you want to customization on addtocart template file in Magento 2, You can override `addtocart.phtml` file in your module by below way,

Create the `catalog_product_view.xml` file in your module,
Path: `app/code/{VendorName}/{PackageName}/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * 
 * @package VendorName_PackageName
 */
-->
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">VendorName_PackageName::product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">VendorName_PackageName::product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

`product.info.addtocart` and `product.info.addtocart.additional` block contains the addtocart template file.

Now you have to create template file addtocart.phtml in your module at below location,
`app/code/{VendorName}/{PackageName}/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml`

copy the clone of template from Core Catalog module’s `addtocart.phtml` file and do your customization.

**I hope this will help**

Comment: I have already create all files, and add addtocart.phtml, but above code working only for configurable and simple products, but i want override bungle products for example